# ASP.NET Core JWT Authentication for MVC and Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, jwt

I am building an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API project that also serves up Razor pages.  My plan is to have users authenticate using a Razor page, but also provide secure Web API endpoints for use with AJAX calls. I have implemented JWT Authorization for the Web API, and hoped to use JWT Authentication for the Razor pages as well. The problem is that I can't find any examples of using JWT with Razor pages.  Others have asked similar questions, but with no real answers ([ASP.NET Core 2.2 JWT Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699789/asp-net-core-2-2-jwt-authentication)).

I added this to ConfigureServices to configure Jwt:

```
services.AddScoped<JwtAuthenticationEvents>();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Jwt";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Jwt";
}).AddJwtBearer("Jwt", options =>
{
    options.EventsType = typeof(JwtAuthenticationEvents);
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
}).AddCookie("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
});
```

And created a new JwtAuthenticationEvents class, similar to what I have done with Cookie Validation:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationEvents : JwtBearerEvents
{
    private readonly IRepo _repo;

    public JwtAuthenticationEvents(IRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public override async Task Challenge(JwtBearerChallengeContext context)
    {
        var userPrincipal = context;
    }

    public override async Task MessageReceived(MessageReceivedContext context)
    {
        var userPrincipal = context.Principal;
    }

    public override async Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        var userPrincipal = context.Principal;
        ...
    }
}
```

The JwtAuthenticationEvents class seems to be working, with the Challenge method being hit when I load a page with the [Authorize] attribute, but then I just get a 401 error. I am trying to figure out how to redirect to the Login form so I can create a token. Going directly to Login also gives a 401. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any thoughts on this? Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: One update. Now instead of getting a 401 error when trying to load the Login Razor page directly, I get this error:  "No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Bearer'. The registered sign-out schemes are: Cookies. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookies("Bearer",...)?","